# Snowflake: Regex with "?"

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake as a database and trying to match a string based on a regular expression substring.

Specifically, I'm doing:

`REGEXP_SUBSTR('(hey)', '(?)')`

I would expect `True` from this but I get:

```
Invalid regular expression: '(?)', no argument for repetition operator: ?
```

I looked through the docs but didn't see anything about `?` being used differently in Snowflake regexes.

Any idea why it ignores the left parenthesis?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I would expect `True` from this "* - based on what?

Comment: You cannot quantify the start of the pattern.

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR returns the string that matches the regexp or null if no maches are found, you can't expect true from that.

Comment: `?` means that the pattern to the left of it is optional. But you don't have any pattern to the left of `?`. What are you trying to match with it?

Comment: Also, `(` and `)` have special meaning in regular expressions. If you want to match them literally, you have to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions have a general *Grouping Construct*.
They encapsulate sub-expressions and are equivalent to *scope*.

In the general form, it consists of a pairing of open and closed parenthesis `( )`,
which are just 2 regex control codes in a list of codes called *meta-characters*.

In the beginning, this was the only way to group constructs and it also
doubled as a capture mechanism.

Along came the need to expand grouping into other uses.

So they started adding more characters after the *opening parenthesis* `(<here>`
to get the different meanings.

It has evolved into these other *Grouping Construct* meanings:
(this is just a sample)

`(?:` `)`  Cluster group, does not capture.
`(?!` `)`  Assertion, negative look ahead.
`(?<!` `)`  Assertion, negative look behind.
`(?=` `)`  Assertion, positive look ahead.
`(?<=` `)`  Assertion, positive look behind.
`(?M)`  Inline modifier (where M = s,m,i).
`(?'abc'` `)`  Named capture group.
`(?<abc>` `)`  Named capture group (alternative).
`(?P<abc>` `)`  Named capture group (alternative - Python).
`(*abc)`  Backtracking control verbs.
`(?(abc)` `|)`  Conditional, where *abc* can be many different things.

`(?(DEFINE)` `)`  Special Conditional *DEFINE*, where it is always true
and it's contents are never executed in mainline code.
This is the place to put function definitions.

`(?#` `)`  Inline code comment.
`(?>` `)`  Atomic group.
`(?1)`  Function call to group number.
`(?&abc)`  Function call to named group.
`(?{` `})`  Code construct (Perl).

You can also notice that the question mark `?` follows the parenthesis in all
but the backtracking control verbs.

The question mark in this case is not a meta-character, but the beginning token of a sequence
of characters that identify what the grouping construct is.

Without the *ending* sequence of the preamble (past the question mark), the engine
parser has no real identity of the grouping construct,
so it falls back to the last valid grouping construct which is the general capture group
`(` `)`.

The it starts to parse the contents of the group.

`(?)` In your case the first construct is a `?`.
This is a quantifier meta-character that modifies an object (what comes before it).
Since the compiler sees the grouping construct as settled business,
it throws the error that this quantifier, *quantifies nothing*.

```
     (                             # (1 start)
=         ?  <-- Quantifies nothing
     )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: I appreciate the very thorough elucidation, but can we also eli5?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documents [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) is for getting the sub-string that matches, thus you will never get `TRUE`, but you might get a non `NULL` answer.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('(hey)', '\\(\\w+\\)');
```

gives `(hey)` as the answer

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('(hey)', '\\(\\w+\\)') IS NOT NULL;
```

therefore gives you `TRUE` but it is simpler to use

```
SELECT REGEXP_LIKE('(hey)', '\\(\\w+\\)');
```